# I want help how to generate random unique identity numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I created a page to modify the user, and I wanted to give some people a unique ID number like 111222 - 996688-7775568 - 222999 i.e. create a list with unique ID numbers such as the attachment How can I do this instead of writing a number in the field, it becomes a list of distinct numbers from which I choose By category of excellence like the attached example

[image]

The code for the page you created:

```
<?php
$target = escape($_POST['target']);
$user = userDetails($target);
    global $mysqli, $data, $lang;
    $rooms = $mysqli->query(" SELECT * FROM  rooms  ORDER BY room_id asc");
?>
<div class="pad_box">
<div class="live_form">
        <p class="label">User ID number:</p>
        <?php 
            $user_id = $user['user_id'];
        if($user['custom_user_id'] != '')
          {
            $user_id = $user['custom_user_id'];
          
        }
?>
<?= $user_id;  ?>
        <input  id="custom_user_id" value="" type="number" min="0" class="full_input">
  </div>
    <div class="live_form">
        <p class="label">Level:</p>
        <input  id="custom_user_level" value="<?= $user['user_level']; ?>" type="number" min="0" class="full_input">
    </div>
    <div class="live_form">
        <p class="label">Likes:</p>
        <input  id="custom_user_like" value="<?= $user['profile_like']; ?>" type="number" min="0" class="full_input">
    </div>
    <div class="live_form">
        <p class="label">Points:</p>
        <input  id="custom_user_point" value="<?= $user['quiz_score']; ?>" type="number" min="0" class="full_input">
    </div>
    <div class="setting_element ">
        <p class="label">the room:</p>
        <select id="custom_user_room">
          <?php     while ($room = $rooms->fetch_assoc()){ ?>

            <option <?php if($room['room_id'] == $user['user_roomid']){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?= $room['room_id']; ?>"><?= $room['room_name']; ?></option>
          
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
 
    <button onclick="saveUserSetting(<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>);" class="reg_button theme_btn"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> <?php echo $lang['save']; ?></button>
    <button class="cancel_over reg_button default_btn">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not generate some random numbers and call it done? Just test that they don't already exist in the database, as in ensure that the `INSERT` on a table with a `UNIQUE` constrained column succeeds.

Comment: Essentially, if it's random, it ain't unique.